# Vim ignore terminal color schemes when setting colors

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, line-numbers

I don't want `vim` to be affected by my terminal's color scheme.

Is there a way to do this?

In particular, I want my `LineNr` column to be colored black.

---

I have seen it is possible because airline manages to do it:

[image]

However, my terminal seems to have changed the meanings of `black`, `blue` etc.

[image]

Comment: If your $TERM does NOT already contain the string `-256color`, then it seems like *one* of your terminal colors is in fact black (because as you point out, you can see it on your screen). You can either check your terminal config to see how the actual black colour is named, or you could just try them all until you find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using color names like `cyan` or `black` or numbers below `16` you are actively telling Vim to use your terminal color scheme.

If you don't want Vim to use your terminal emulator color scheme you will have to:

1. make sure your `$TERM` contains the string `-256color`,
2. use color numbers from 16 to 255.

For 1, possible values are `xterm-256color`, `screen-256color` (in screen and tmux), `rxvt-unicode-256color`, etc.

For 2, you can use [this handy chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Xterm_256color_chart.svg) for reference.

Comment: My terminal seems to support even more colors than are on that chart, is there a way I can access those?

Comment: @theonlygusti See `:help 'termguicolors'`.